# Access variable inside of the iframe? ColdFusion

Tags: variables, iframe, coldfusion, session-variables

I have main cfm page where I set few variables that I would like to use in my app. Here is my `Main.cfm` page:

```
<cfset adminAccess = false>
<cfset userAccess = false>
<cfset app = 'myApp'>

<!--- Grab User Information and Permissions --->
<cfinvoke component="components.appEntry" method="getRecord" returnvariable="CHKAccess">
    <cfinvokeargument name="user" value="#REQUEST.userdata.AppUser#"/>
    <cfinvokeargument name="app" value="#app#"/>
</cfinvoke>

<cfif CHKAccess.RecordCount EQ 1>
    <cfif CHKAccess.AdminAccess EQ 'Y'>
        <cfset adminAccess = true>
    </cfif>
    <cfif CHKAccess.UserAccess EQ 'Y'>
        <cfset userAccess = true>
    </cfif>
</cfif>
<iframe src="appHome.cfm" name="appFrame" id="appFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Here is my `appHome.cfm`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=11" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />  
    <title>App Home</title>
</head>
<body>
     <cfoutput>#adminAccess#</cfoutput>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to output variable content that I previously defined in my `Main.cfm` but I got an error:

```
Detail  [empty string]
ErrNumber   0
Message     Variable ADMINACCESS is undefined.
```

I'm wondering if I have to move my variables in `appHome.cfm`? Or there is other way to access these variables? I haven't worked a lot with iframes and if someone can help me understand this please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: could you just move all your cf into appHome.cfm?

Comment: @luke I could do that. Second option is to set URL variables on my iframe source. I'm wondering what is the best practice to do this and is there any security threat doing it one way or the other? Thank you.

Comment: if you set your iframe with something like appHome.cfm?adminAccess=false that would be a danger - easy to change to true

Comment: What's the purpose of the iframe?

Comment: @DanBracuk I use iframe because this should be a separate app in my system. System has two iframes already. First iframe is AppHeader and second iframe is AppMenu. My iframe is inside of AppMenu iframe. Should I maybe use include instead of iframe? I'm just trying to implement my code in exiting systemand I couldn't change original structure of the code.

Comment: @espresso_coffee Hope the answer for your query is in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141301/in-coldfusion-variables-in-what-scope-can-be-passed-to-and-iframe-page